# Cannot connect Azure Web apps to Azure Database

Tags: asp.net, azure, connection-string

i have deploy an Azure website and Azure database for it. my website is a MVC website with Account Controller that need username and password to get in using asp .net. i've made the account for login. everything is okay until i login. my Azure apps throw exception that i assume that my web apps cannot connect to my Azure Database.

[image: Login Error]

so i deploy it again in my local machine with local database to check whether my apps is working or not .

here is the list the thing that i've done and the result of login page :

- use local machine to local database (Success)
- use local machine to azure database (Success)
- use Azure website to Azure Database (fail)

i've point my web apps to azure database in Azure Management Portal like like this
[image: My Data Connection in Azure]

and also the connection string in Web.config file like this

```
<add key="CMMSConnectionString" value="Data Source=tcp:(my azure database server).database.windows.net,1433;User ID=(my username);Password=(my password);Initial Catalog=(my azure database);" />
```

this exact same connection string worked from my local website.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.
NOTE : CMMS is the name of my project

Comment: In DB > Firewall Services have you ticked 'Allow access to Azure services' ?

Comment: @NeilThompson yes i have.

Comment: Are you sure it is the DB connection that is failing?

Comment: i thing so @juunas , because in my local machine i've ever face the same problem with exactly same error message when i forgot to change the connection string to connect my apps to database .

Comment: @IrfanDary did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

From the call stack, this does not appear to be a SQL Azure based exception.  Is there any non-SQL callouts to other web services/API's in your ValidateEmployee callback?

Comment: okay, i'll check that, but i still dont understand why there is no problem when i connect my local apps to Azure database. i can use my apps properly. i can login, input data, etc .